# getResult() method Doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine, row

What is the format of the array returned using the getResult() method in the following example, using Doctrine and Symfony2:

```
$query = $this->_em->createQuery('SELECT p.id, p.nameProduct FROM ArkiglassProductBundle:Product p');
        return $query->getResult();
```

And I would like to know how to access each case and print every row.

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php
$query = $em->createQuery('SELECT u.username, u.name FROM CmsUser u');
$users = $query->getResults(); // array of CmsUser username and name values
echo $users[0]['username'];
```

taken from the [doctrine documentation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#dql-select-examples)

Comment: yes, iknow, i red that part, but things are not clear for me what '0' means and how to print all results in a loop, i approciate ur help

Comment: `$users[0]` is the first array element result

Answer (score 2):

The query returns an array of Users:

```
array(
    0 => array(username => 'aaa', name => 'bbb'),
    1 => array(username => 'ccc', name => 'ddd')
)
```

So the $users[0] element means the first user in the list.

You can use a for loop to iterate:

```
{% for user in users %}
    {{ user.username }} - {{ user.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you asking about "0" in $users[0]? 
I hope I am not misunderstanding your question.
getResults() returns an array of database results. Once you've given your array a name you can access each element using the index. 
Of course if you want to loop over it you will probably use a foreach loop so you won't have to use the index:

```
$products = $query->getResults();
foreach ($products as $product){
    echo $product->id.' '.$product->nameProduct;
}
```

This said... this pseudo code is here for the sake of explanation. If you are using Symfony you will have to display your results in a view file, probably using twig like Manuszep did in his example.
In his case you will have to use a for in loop like he did.

Comment: You should use $product->getId() and $product->getNameProduct(); which are public methods. You cannot access $product->id and $product->nameProduct as they are private.